# How to cite an interactive dataviz (Shiny app)?

Tags: citations

For my next paper I am going to provide a link to an interactive data visualization created using [Rstudio's Shiny](https://www.shinyapps.io) framework. How can I properly cite it?

Comment: Why not cite it like any other website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I cite a website URL?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-should-i-cite-a-website-url)

Answer (score 1):

You could cite it the way you would cite R packages, example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-cite-packages/

Or you can check out how it is cited following different citation benchmarks using Google scholar. See here on [Yihui Xie's page](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=lkjqsd4AAAAJ&hl=en#d=gs_md_cita-d&u=%2Fcitations%3Fview_op%3Dview_citation%26hl%3Den%26user%3Dlkjqsd4AAAAJ%26citation_for_view%3Dlkjqsd4AAAAJ%3AO3NaXMp0MMsC%26tzom%3D-60)

Or you can indeed cite it as a website, as @ff524 added.