# How to Reference to Online Articles

Tags: citations

What is the right method to follow when referencing an article published on a website?

For example, I want to include the below sentence from [this article](https://arstechnica.com/science/2016/02/the-audacious-rescue-plan-that-might-have-saved-space-shuttle-columbia/).

> A mere 81.7 seconds later, a chunk of insulating foam tore free from the orange external tank and smashed into the leading edge of the orbiter's left wing at a relative velocity of at least 400 miles per hour (640 kph), but Columbia continued to climb toward orbit.

Is the below a correct way to do so?

"A mere 81.7 seconds later, a chunk of insulating foam tore free from the orange external tank and smashed into the leading edge of the orbiter's left wing at a relative velocity of at least 400 miles per hour (640 kph), but Columbia continued to climb toward orbit."

Under References:

Hutchinson, L, 2016. 'The audacious rescue plan that might have saved space shuttle Columbia, USA, *ARS Technicia*

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-should-i-cite-a-website-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the web isn't a permanent repository, either reference something that is, or give the date on which you access the web article as part of the reference. And in your example, give the URL at which you found the article, not just the title of the website. So, more like this:

> Hutchinson, L, 2016. 'The audacious rescue plan that might have saved space shuttle Columbia, USA, ARS Technicia: https://arstechnica.com/science/2016/02/the-audacious-rescue-plan-that-might-have-saved-space-shuttle-columbia/, accessed April 1, 2020.

The [Internet Archive](https://archive.org) and its Wayback Machine is permanent, but the date will be required for resources that change.

Comment: Thank you, Buffy. If I also ask, in the body text of the research, in addition to the quotes, should I add anything? As in, (Hutchinson, L, ARS Technicia)?