# How to cite JavaDoc?

Tags: citations, thesis, computer-science

Writing a technical Master's degree thesis in the IT field, I need to cite sentences that are in the JavaDoc, where are no author and no year. Ex.

- From: [`java.util.Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html)

  > The Queue interface does not define the blocking queue methods, which are common in concurrent programming
- From: [`org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicator.html)

  > Strategy interface used to contribute Health to the results returned from the HealthEndpoint.

Unlike the first one, the second has a base webpage [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/index.html) which shows 14 authors (I know to cite multiple authors). Can be the latter JavaDoc be cited with these authors? How about the first one?

How to cite **both** of them?

---

Edit: I have checked the [How should I cite a website URL?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-should-i-cite-a-website-url) question, however, the point of my question is that I might cite from multiple classes, where the URL changes. Yeah, little, but still, so it is actually a **different** source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I cite a website URL?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-should-i-cite-a-website-url)

Comment: I have checked that. The point is I don't cite a website from a random anonymous article, but a *reference and API documentation* that was/is written by either authors mentioned in the root website or by company representatives.

Comment: Related: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/31786