# How To cite a Youtube Channel in LaTex

Tags: citations, latex

I am currently writing a research article and I need to cite a Youtube channel in my (LaTex) references. How can I do that? I know how to do it with a single video. But how to do it with the channel as a whole, like [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/telfaz11)?

Comment: You really shouldn't cite a complete channel. You also wouldn't cite just an author name without specifying which article or book.

Comment: Thanks, @BrtH Actually I am using the content in the channel in the research, so may I can cite it as a URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I cite a website URL?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-should-i-cite-a-website-url)

Comment: This sounds like a technical LaTeX question which would make it off topic here. I presume that OP understands what information to communicate to readers (such as channel name, URL, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Youtube channel is uniquely defined by the channel url, so you should probably cite that. (See for example [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file) on the TeX stack on how to do that.) You'll need to think of something to enter into the "author" field, which, depending on the channel, may be hard. For "title" you should probably enter the name of the channel. Or use the name of the channel as author and use "Youtube channel" as title.

Comment: I would prefer the second option: name of the channel  as the author and Youtube Channel as title. Unless you refer to a particular video of the channel.